# Connecting Platform Events to Amazon SQS/SNS

Tags: platform-event, aws

I have a requirement where I need to subscribe to Salesforce Platform Events via AWS. I did some research and found out that we can do so via Lambda. However Lambda has its own limitations. Is it possible to push Platform Events to either SQS or SNS. Please help me in this regards.

Thanks,
Anant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Out of the box - no. Apps hosted outside of SF platform can listen to platform event messages by subscribing to a channel through CometD protocol. Neither SQS nor SNS speak CometD. A typical solution is to push messages into SQS or SNS from Salesforce in parallel to or instead of publishing a platform event. This is pretty straightforward and can be done via an [Apex REST callout](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_integration_services/apex_integration_rest_callouts).

UPDATE: in mid-2022, SF announced general availability of their new event bus which speaks gRPC. Neither SQS nor SNS support gRPC out of the box, thus the solution architecture above still applies.

Comment: Can we do the callouts through future methods from a trigger.

Comment: @Anant Yes, that works.